# RESTful загрузка файла с кастомными заголовками

Tags: html, rest, xmlhttprequest

Есть **multipart/form-data** форма для загрузки файла.

Предположим мы используем jQuery Form для создания iframe окна где создается наша форма и реализуется непосредственно отправка.

Как внедрить в процесс загрузки файла кастомный заголовок, например Accept?

```
Accept: application/vnd.company.myapp-v2+json
Content-Type: application/vnd.company.myapp-v2+json
```

Как мне кажется мы имеем лишь доступ к изменению непосредственно полей формы. Как при этом изменить http заголовок я не представляю.

Знаю, что новая версия XHR2 позволяет загружать файлы, но как мы можем быть уверены, что все пользователи имеют достаточно функциональный браузер для этой технологии? Хотелось бы удовлетворить желания всех пользователей. Если понадобится бегать вокруг загрузки файла с бубном, я хотел бы услышать от профессионалов советы и решения в данном вопросе.

Вы скажете, можно добавить дополнительное поле, содержащее версию,
но расширять интерфейс и порождать костыль ради костыля - плохая практика.

Как обойти несовершенство технологии xmlhttprequest v1 и остаться человеком?

Спасибо.

> *Предыстория (необязательно к прочтению):*
>
> *Началось все с того, что приложение которое мне пришлось поддерживать*
> *не использует какие-либо современные паттерны проектирования или хорошие практики.*
>
> Мной было решено не переписывать весь код, который наследили до меня, а добавить 2 версию механизмов взаимодействия и поэтапно переносить нагрузку на frontend, чтобы сделать код более читаемым и дружелюбным.

Comment: Тут можно посмотреть, тот же вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597685/setting-headers-when-using-jquery-form-plugin

Comment: В этом вопросе на англоязычном ресурсе нет ни одного полезного комментария, кроме того, что iframe не предполагает кастомных заголовков, что и так было ясно. Я предполагаю услышать более развернутый ответ, например какие-то костыли которые предполагают загрузку файла с кастомными заголовками, на ум приходит flash-костыль или что-то вроде, может есть более лаконичное решение вопроса.